# How to identify the field I'm sending via submit in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using the component [InPlaceEdit](https://svelte.dev/repl/29c1026dda3c47a187bd21afa0782df1?version=4.2.2) and I'm trying to change a text in a table.

When I make a change in the text, this makes an API call and update the value.

However, I don't know how to identify what field I'm requesting to modify therefore I have it hardcoded at the moment.

So let's say I have categories, expenses and savings and each of them have id, name, price, etc..

so to access the values it would be categories.id or categories.name

I would like the code to recognise what exactly I'm changing.

This is my

```
onMount(async function () {
        const endpoint = 'http://blablabla/'
        const response = await fetch(endpoint)
        const data = await response.json()
        ExpenseStore.set(data)
    })

    function submit(field) {
        
        return ({detail: newValue}) => {
            
                const endpoint = `http://blablabla/${field.id}`
                let data = new FormData()

                field.toArray().forEach((concept, index) => {
                    const num2 = data[index];
                    console.log(concept, num2);
                })

                /*
                SOLUTION
                FOR EACH data and FIELD
                IF DATA[0] == FIELD[0] (en valor) 
                    then data.append(field[0].meta, field[0]])
                ELSE
                    data.append(field[0].meta, newValue)
                */

                data.append('name', newValue)
                data.append('expensecategory', field.expensecategory)
                data.append('monthly_amount', field.monthly_amount)
                data.append('payment_frequency', field.payment_frequency)
                data.append('year', field.year)
                data.append('yearly_amount', field.yearly_amount)

                fetch(endpoint , {method: 'PUT', body: data}).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                })
            // IRL: POST value to server here
            console.log(`updated ${field.id}, new value is: "${newValue}"`)
        }
    }
```

This is the logic I think I should follow but I cannot make it work

```
SOLUTION
FOR EACH data and FIELD
IF DATA[0] == FIELD[0] (en valor) 
    then data.append(field[0].meta, field[0]])
ELSE
    data.append(field[0].meta, newValue)
```

And this is the body:

```
{#each $ExpenseStore as expense, index (expense.id)}
<html code>                         
    <InPlaceEdit bind:value={expense.name} on:submit={submit(expense)}/>
<html code>
{/each}
```

I'm thinking, how can I send the metadata of the object via submit or bind?
So for example, if I was able to send 'name' from expense.name, I could modify just that field. So what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just extend your submit function and pass in the name?

```js
function submit(field, property) { ...
```

```html
<InPlaceEdit bind:value={expense.name} on:submit={submit(expense, 'name')}/>
```

This should also work with a variable in case of a loop:

```html
<InPlaceEdit bind:value={expense[property]} on:submit={submit(expense, property)}/>
```

Comment: Oh jeez, too many hours programming can make everything foggy! Would you know anyway of instead of putting 'name' we could retrieve that from "expense".

So expense would be for example:
{ name: 'mortgage', amount: '600'}

How could I access to "name" from expense?

Comment: I don't think you logically can, if there are multiple properties to be edited. `Object.keys` returns all property names, but how would you know which one is currently being edited?